# exit from ssh killing the running matlab code

Tags: matlab, ssh, remote-server

I am new to using a remote server, and my knowledge about it is limited. I would like to utilize my institute's server to run MATLAB from my Windows 10 system. To begin the process, I initiate Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and download Ubuntu. Then, I execute the following inputs

```
username@LAPTOP-4KB3S7C0:~$ ssh -X sagar.1997_r@IP address
sagar.1997_r@IP address's password:
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-70-generic x86_64)

Username@Matlab-X:~$ matlab
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
```

After completing the aforementioned steps, I successfully accessed the MATLAB interface and managed to run code. However, a persistent issue arose where MATLAB would automatically stop whenever I closed the terminal. I employed both `tmux` and `screen` in an attempt to address the issue, but unfortunately, they did not provide a solution. It is possible that I might not have used them correctly or effectively

**for tmux** I write the following:

```
sagar.1997_r@Matlab-X:~$ tmux
```

then a new session start:

```
sagar.1997_r@Matlab-X:~$ matlab
```

and I run the matlab code. Then I detach the session and Matlab is running in the background.

After detaching the session with `tmux` or `screen`, MATLAB seems to be running in the background. However, there are still issues when it comes to maintaining the session's stability. If a connection loss occurs or if I shut down the laptop, the MATLAB session is lost. Upon trying to log in again via `ssh -X` and attaching the previous session, I encounter error messages such as 'connection lost' or 'disconnected pipes', indicating that the session couldn't be restored properly.

Comment: So you have MATLAB running remotely through SSH, and the MATLAB desktop is showing on your desktop? If you turn off the laptop, the SSH connection drops, killing the process on the other end. `tmux` disconnects MATLAB from the terminal, but the graphics are still tunneled through SSH. It seems to me that you want to run MATLAB without the desktop or graphics (`-nodisplay`), but then you do need the terminal to interact with it, so you must connect and disconnect it. What is the use case? Why keep MATLAB open? Describing your goal might help in getting a useful answer.

Comment: If you need to forward x11, and still be able to disconnect, you could try http://xpra.org/

Comment: @CrisLuengoThank you for your response! I have a MATLAB code that I need to run on my institute's server from my laptop. However, the code might take a considerable amount of time (approx two days) to complete. In order to avoid keeping my laptop on and connected to the internet during this entire duration, I would like to detach the session but have my code continue running on the remote server.
 When I return and reattach the session later, I expect to be able to view the progress of my code or obtain the desired result, such as the plotted figure

Comment: If [xrdp](https://www.xrdp.org/) is available on your institute's server, a remote desktop connection could be an alternative solution.